# Get Value from XML string

Tags: java, android, xml, api, languagetool

I am trying to get the value of "msg" from the returned XML response, As you can see "msg" is found twice. How can i get all values of "msg" from the returned response?

Here is a sample of the returned value "msg" is found in error:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<matches software="LanguageTool" version="2.6-SNAPSHOT" buildDate="2014-05-26 09:16">
  <language shortname="en-US" name="English (US)" />
  <error fromy="0" fromx="0" toy="0" tox="4" ruleId="UPPERCASE_SENTENCE_START" msg="This sentence does not start with an uppercase letter" replacements="This" context="this is a error" contextoffset="0" offset="0" errorlength="4" category="Capitalization" locqualityissuetype="typographical" />
  <error fromy="0" fromx="8" toy="0" tox="9" ruleId="EN_A_VS_AN" msg="Use 'an' instead of 'a' if the following word starts with a vowel sound, e.g. 'an article', 'an hour'" replacements="an" context="this is a error" contextoffset="8" offset="8" errorlength="1" category="Miscellaneous" locqualityissuetype="misspelling" />
</matches>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try Google's recommended XML parsing method as described in https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to XML parsing , this will be great help.

http://www.sitepoint.com/learning-to-parse-xml-data-in-your-android-app/

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Simple is a Java Library for XML that works nicely on Android.
See
* http://simple.sourceforge.net/ 
* http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#deserialize
* http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/examples/examples.php

The idea is to map XML to Java. The approach is similar to JaxB but as the library names says "simpler".

Here is a snippet along which lines it might work

```java
@Root
public class Match {

   @Path("error/[1]")
   @Attribute
   private String msg;

}
```